# Why would the r^2 values of the same data set but separated be lower?

Tags: regression, linear

I have a set of data on one year(11 months, janv-nov), for each day I have the "load" and the "prod hours". I try to predict the prod hours thanks to the load. So i'm fitting a linear regression in my data.  It has an `r^2 = 40%.`

[image: This is the full year plot]

When I separate my data into two blocks :
block1 = Jan-to-April + October-to-November
block2 = May-to-Sept

**Block1**
[image: This is the Off-peak plot]

**Block2**

[image: This is the peak plot]

off-peak month (Jan-to-April + October-to-November) = `r^2 of 19%`

Peak months: May-to-Sept = `r^2 of 37%`

Why would the r^2 values of both relationships go down?

Comment: First of all, be carefull with a regression to analyse time serie, bescause it doesn't respond to the first criteria of the method: the independance of the variable. Second pont, can you show us the plot of your serie ? it would be easier to answer you.

Comment: every point refer to one day ? and can you put a title for each graph ? and how do you calculate the R2 ?